# Punctuation of a question preceded by a semicolon

Tags: punctuation

Is this sentence properly punctuated ( specifically the ending question mark)?

> "Having said that, it is again unlikely to ponder deep  into a
>   question; Is it too late to make a move?"

Comment: It certainly looks like a question and, therefore, needs the question mark. Why are  you concerned about the punctuaton?

Comment: Actually, I am confused about whether the question following semicolon needs to be ended by a full stop( considering the complex sentence) or by a question mark (as demanded by the question).

Comment: Subject of this sentence is not clear.

Comment: The semicolon acts rather like a period, almost making the rest of the sentence a _new_ sentence. _Almost_. To the extent that you add the necessary question mark, but don't capitalise the word following the semicolon (unless it's 'I', a proper noun etc).

Comment: The issue I see is the semicolon itself. As you point to and introduce your question, I'd prefer a colon: "a question: Is it too late ..."

Comment: Review the use of colon in "a question: Is it too late..."

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Is that the only difference, or do we have to be careful with the type of sentence the LHS of the semicolon is, too? For example, if the LHS is an exclamatory sentence while the RHS is not, then we couldn't join them with a semicolon, because the LHS would be unclear on account of lack of the exclamation mark, right?

Comment: @He I'm not sure there are situations where an exclamatory independent clause needing an exclamation mark doesn't pack enough punch to make a continuation reasonable. Double punctuation used judiciously has been said to be 'not unacceptable in BrE' (whatever 'BrE' is), and I use it occasionally, but that rarely includes semicolons except in extreme circumstances such as << The coded message read 'The bRown & §ØŦƈ%$ cow landz @d@a#w#n??!;;:;;', but I couldn't understand it. >> Seriously, exact rendering of quotes of written sources can pose quite a problem.

Comment: @Edwin: So are there no rough rules of thumb as to joining which types of sentences using a semicolon would probably be a bad idea? That is, the LHS and RHS of the semicolon can freely be any combination of exclamatory, declarative, interrogative, and imperative sentence? // And what about when more than 2 sentences are juxtaposed using semicolons?

Comment: @HeW A _very_ good rule of thumb is 'no more than one semicolon-used-as-a-semicolon per sentence'. / A good r-o-t is 'don't use semicolons very often'. / As I say above, independent clauses requiring an exclamation mark wouldn't seem to lend themselves to not ending the sentence. Mid-sentence question marks have been covered here before; I can't see that running text can utilise combinations of '?' and ';'. Punctuating fragments is an art in itself.

Comment: @Edwin: Can you clarify what you meant by this: "... independent clauses requiring an exclamation mark wouldn't seem to lend themselves to not ending the sentence"; I'd thought I understood it correctly when you said something similar in your earlier comment dated April 1, but now I'm not so sure? In that earlier comment, I took your first sentence to mean that an independent clause lacking (= "requiring") an exclamation mark can *always* be juxtaposed with another independent clause using a semicolon. But in the above-quoted sentence, you seem to saying the opposite -- viz. that ...

Comment: [contd.] they can *never* be juxtaposed with another clause using a semicolon...

Comment: The statement was clumsy, involving a double negative. _Independent clauses ending in an exclamation mark, and most of those ending in a question mark, would not be improved (far from it) by a continuation of the sentence._ "Drop your gun!" "How beautiful you are!" and "When did you last see your father?" are almost certainly not going to be improved by tacking on a second independent clause: another sentence is what is required next. Sometimes, multiple question marks are used in a sentence, but not with a semicolon too. // ...

Comment: Your example sounds unnatural, but the form (apart from the capital I) is not problematic. The question has to follow naturally from the statement in the main clause. "_We're out of milk; are you going to the supermarket this afternoon?_" but *"_We're out of milk; do you think the Labour Party will win the next election?_"

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks for the helpful comments! :) I still have a point of confusion, though -- re "Independent clauses **ending** in an exclamation mark, and most of those **ending** in a question mark..." (emphasis added): Is it clear that my question was about the first clauses *lacking* their end-punctuation ('?', '!', whatever), as the semicolon has taken its place; and so the unsightly nature of a putative double punctuation should not have any bearing on your judgment on whether exclamatory and interrogative sentences are amenable to a continuation?  // "Your example sounds ...

Comment: [contd.] unnatural, but the form (apart from the capital I) is not problematic." -- I'm not the OP! ;-) Unless you were talking about the semicolon usage in my comment yesterday? But the capital 'I' there is not problematic, since 'I' is always capitalised.

Comment: (b) Sorry; too busy thinking English. (a) Although there are examples somewhere on ELU containing sentence-medial (and multiple) question marks, I'd say that these are rare and should be used with caution. I can't see that sentence-medial exclamation marks are ever needed (except in parentheses); I'd always use a fragment if I needed to.

Comment: @Edwin: We seem to be  somehow having a misunderstanding: my question has not been about double punctuation. I meant to clarify that in the previous pair of comments. If it was unclear: I just meant to ask whether your judgment that exclamatory & interrogative sentences are very rarely improved by a semicolon-continuation was motivated at all by you possibly misunderstanding my question to be asking about a semicolon-continuation when both punctuation marks are kept, when in fact I've only ever meant my question for the normal usage, where the end-punctuation before the semicolon is dropped.

Comment: I'm lost. If you have a question, clarify it and put it as a 'question'. The question here asks about "Having said that, it is again unlikely to ponder deep into a question; Is it too late to make a move?" [Dec I-Clause (after sentence-connector)] + [Int I-Clause (semantically related to first clause)]. Fine in principle apart from the capitalisation of 'is', though 'ponder deep into' is very dubious.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Okay, I still don't see the cause of the apparent miscommunication here, but as the questions I have asked in the comments here are not very related to the one in the OP, they might be considered off-topic and would be better as a separate site question, so I'll leave it at this. Once again, thanks for all the helpful replies! :)

Comment: I'm unclear as to the meaning of the first part, but a colon might work nicely instead of a semicolon if you mean, specifically "...this question:  Is it too late to make a move?"

Answer (score -1):

The end question mark is appropriate, but the sentence doesn't really make sense.
I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to say, but if I were writing this sentence I would probably go with something like:
Having said that, it is again unlikely that I (or he/she/they) will ponder too deeply the question "Is it too late to make a move?".

Comment: Thank you very much for  the suggestion.